# Whats the meaning of '+' symbol in Jenkins log?

Tags: jenkins, haxelib

I am trying to compile one lib using haxelib. When I make that manually in windows cmd all work well, but when I make a build with Jenkins using a "Exectue Windows batch command" in the configuration, the result is::

```
>haxelib run hxcpp Build.xml
+
```

No more details, no more log, only that and exit 1 instruction.

Whats is the meaning of '+' symbol? Is a haxelib problem? Jenkins?

Comment: did you try running the command with debug or verbose mode on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` prefix comes from the shell, not from Jenkins. Observe that the shell is called with the `-xe` command line options. The `-x` activates a trace. From the [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) on the Bash man page:

> **-x**
>
> Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are executed. The value of the **`PS4`** variable is expanded and the resultant value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

If you scroll down on the man page to the [Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) section, you find the explanation for PS4:

> **PS4**
>
> The value of this parameter is expanded like PS1 and the expanded value is the prompt printed before the command line is echoed when the `-x` option is set (see [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)). The first character of the expanded value is replicated multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection. The default is `‘+ ’`.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my logs it precedes shell commands:

```
[...] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4228279081525071028.sh
+ git submodule foreach git checkout master
...
+ git submodule foreach git pull --rebase
...
[...] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson362703066220469941.sh
+ git add -u .
[...] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/CommandInterpreterCondition1891071927593818802.sh
+ git commit -m ...
```